# Changed security settings and now I can't run any scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

I went into my account security settings and cleaned up several old application which I no longer use, Clicked on Remove Access.
Then I went back to the Google App Script I was working on (and was working fine) and tried to run it:

```
Cannot connect to Gmail (line 6, file "Code")
Line 6 = var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
```

Tried to edit some code and save

> We're sorry, we were unable to fetch authorization credentials.
>   Please wait a bit and try again.

Tried to create a new script and name it, waited 30 minutes and rebooted my machine, but I still have the same error.

Comment: Tried on another computer, and it worked properly. Went back to original computer, logged out of all accounts, cleared browser cache, shutdown and restarted and it worked properly again.

Answer (score 0):

Just clear cache reauthorize close browser then open again and every thing should work fine otherwise you should visit this link [Gmail help](http://support.google.com)
if you can't find the problem then send google a email at [Contact Google](http://support.google.com/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=portal_contact_options.cs)